# Regular expression to get everything between two characters/strings

Tags: regex

I have been trying to use regular expression to extract data from the following strings

1. `LTE_LTE_FSD9167__P_Airport1`
   I want to extract the 7 digit sitecode(FSD9167) from the above string.
2. `RUR1251__S_KhooNaiWala`
   I want to extract 7 digit sitecode(RUR1251) from above string.

For LTE_LTE case I wrote `LTE_LTE_([^_;]+).*` but it selects the whole string including not the required text only.

Comment: Good to know. What is your question?

Comment: Two examples aren't enough to go on. What are the *exact* rules to determine what is a sitecode and what isn't? For example "Any string of 7 characters in the range A-Z and 0-9, surrounded by either _ or the start/end of the string" or something like that ("three uppercase letters followed by four digits" etc.)

Comment: Help in creating Regular expression to extract the 7 digit sitecodes from the strings mentioned in the question.

Comment: I will only get the above two strings one starting with LTE_LTE(LTE_LTE_FSD9167__P_Airport1) and other starting with the 7 character code(RUR1251__S_KhooNaiWala).
In first case I want to extract 7 characters after (LTE_LTE) i.e. FSD9167 and in second case first 7 characters (i.e RUR1251)
@TimPietzcker

Comment: You'll have to show us what you've tried to achieve the same. SO is not a regex-writing service.

Comment: For LTE_LTE case I wrote LTE_LTE_([^\_;]+).* but I selects the whole string including not the required text only.@CinCout

Comment: In the future, please edit the question to include your attempts. I have done it for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern I see is three letters followed by four numbers, so:

```
\w{3}\d{4}
```

Use `()` to capture the pattern:

```
(\w{3}\d{4})
```

PHP:

```php
$re = '/(\w{3}\d{4})/m';
```

JavaScript:

```js
const regex = /(\w{3}\d{4})/gm;
```

Use https://regex101.com/ to learn the explanation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this:

`^(?:LTE_LTE_)?(\S{7})\S*$ /gm`

This captures the seven non-whitespace characters either at the beginning (case 2) or just after `LTE_LTE_`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wwQMQt/3)

Answer (score -1):

You did not provide any rule about how the code could look like. I noticed that both codes you provided in the example have 3 letters followed by 4 digits. I made a rule more generic, with at least 2 letters followed by at least 3 digits.

The regex is:

```
[a-zA-Z]{2,}\d{3,}
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/DojhjH/1).

Answer (score -1):

As you want to match only these 2 strings, use:

```
(?<![A-Z0-9])[A-Z0-9]{7}(?![A-Z0-9])
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<![A-Z0-9])       # negative lookbehind, make sure we haven't alphanum before
[A-Z0-9]{7}         # 7 alphanumerics
(?![A-Z0-9])        # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't alphanum after
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hpb6L6/1)

Comment: Serial downvoter in action. All answers have been downvoted at same time!